# IOnic angular prod compiler error Property 'md' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

Hi for the following code

```
<ion-segment value="{{selectedWor}}" (ionChange)="worshipTypeChanged($event)" [mode]="md">
```

I am getting the following error when i run: ionic build --prod. (no compiler error without --prod)

> ```
> ERROR in src/app/pages/map/map.html(38,85): Property 'md' does not exist on type 'MapPage'.
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
>
>         ng.cmd run app:build:production exited with exit code 1.
>
>         Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
> ```

Any ideas? The documentation says i can do it..

Here is my ionic info.

> Ionic:
>
> Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.6
>   (C:\Users\ginil\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)    Ionic
>   Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.4
>   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.24    @angular-devkit/schematics
>   : 8.3.20    @angular/cli                  : 8.3.20
>   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0
>
> Cordova:
>
> Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)    Cordova Platforms
>   : not available    Cordova Plugins   : not available
>
> Utility:
>
> cordova-res : 0.5.1    native-run  : 0.2.7
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v11.11.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)    npm    :
>   6.7.0    OS     : Windows 10

Comment: see the 'mode' property in https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using mode as two way binding variable so you have to declare md in ts file.

There are two way to use mode property

1)

```
<ion-segment value="{{selectedWor}}" (ionChange)="worshipTypeChanged($event)" mode="md">
```

2)

### html

```
<ion-segment value="{{selectedWor}}" (ionChange)="worshipTypeChanged($event)" [mode]="md">
```

### ts

md = 'md'